# How to find a WebElement by another WebElement using Page Factory

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Had a brief scan at the source code, not sure what's the best practice for this.

For example, say I have a page object 'DummyPage', which has two panel elements `TopPanel` and `BottomPanel`. Each of the panel has some elements, which are found by `TopPanel.FindElement()` instead of `driver.FindElement()`. How to apply Page Factory for this?

I'm aware of that `PageFactory.InitElements(ISearchContext, Object)` takes in `ISearchContext`, however, I'm not sure how can I use it for the page and the panel elements in one class.

```c#
public class DummyPage {

    private IWebDriver driver;

    public DummyPage(IWebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public IList<IWebElement> DummyLinks {
        get { return driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".some-dummy-links")); }
    }

    public IWebElement TopPanel {
        get { return driver.FindElement(By.Id("top-panel")); }
    }

    public IWebElement BottomPanel {
        get { return driver.FindElement(By.Id("bottom-panel")); }
    }

    public IWebElement FooInTopPanel {
        get { return TopPanel.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".something")); }
    }

    public IWebElement FooInBottomPanel {
        get { return BottomPanel.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".something")); }
    }
}

public class DummyPageWithPageFactory {

    public DummyPageWithPageFactory(IWebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = ".some-dummy-links")]
    public IList<IWebElement> DummyLinks { get; private set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "top-panel")]
    public IWebElement TopPanel { get; private set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "bottom-panel")]
    public IWebElement BottomPanel { get; private set; }

    //public IWebElement FooInTopPanel { get; private set; }
    //public IWebElement FooInBottomPanel { get; private set; }
}
```

If I use `driver.FindElement()` for all instances and concatenate all locators, I might be facing another situation, that all locators are too long and I can't use variables within the C# attributes.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#top-panel .blah .blah .super-long-blah .something")]
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#top-panel .blah .blah .super-long-blah .something-new")]
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#bottom-panel .blah .blah .super-long-blah .something")]
```

Comment: There is a ByChained class available that will allow you to chain your Bys.  Not sure if this is what you are looking for and I'm not sure of the C# syntax (although I know it is in there) as I'm a Java person.  Hopefully a useful pointer if nothing else.

Comment: @Ardesco: Yes, I'm aware of that class, however, I reckon the usage of `ByChained` looks like `driver.FindElement(new ByChained(By.Id("top-panel"), 
By.ClassName("something")));`, which I'm not sure how is this gonna help "Page Factory". But indeed, this class is in `PageObjects` namespace and this question is kind of language specific.

Comment: In Java world you can do @FindBys(@FindBy("locator1"), @FindBy("locator2")).  I assume there is similar syntax for the .NET bindings as ByChained was brought in as part of the page factory code in Java.  I admit I'm making a lot of assumptions here and assuming that the .NET bindings are broadly similar to the Java ones.

Comment: @Ardesco: Yeah, I see the difference here. Java's `@FindBys` allows `By` params, while I need find something similar to put inside C# `[FindsBy()]`. I noticed it allows `CustomFinderType`, however, looks like I need create my own class inheriting `By`in that case, and it takes in `string`, which is not helping me shorten the locator. Thanks mate btw.

Comment: Is elements getting from TopPanel.FindElement() and  BottomPanel.FindElement() is fixed?

Comment: @AnandSomani: What do you mean "fixed"?

Comment: Fixed means Static data. Always getting same element again and again.

Comment: @AnandSomani: Let's say Yes here.

Answer (score 1):

See this [example](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_PageObjects_FindsByAttribute.htm):

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "anElementName", Priority = 0)]
[FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "differentElementName", Priority = 1)]
public IWebElement thisElement;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Have a look at this [page about formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and see if you can fix the link in your answer. It will be a lot more useful for people, and easier to read, if the link worked.